# How does an NTP host switch among the various modes?

Tags: ntp

The [NTPv3 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1305.txt) describes five operating modes:

> Symmetric Active (1): A host operating in this mode sends periodic
>   messages regardless of the reachability state or stratum of its peer. By
>   operating in this mode the host announces its willingness to synchronize
>   and be synchronized by the peer.
>
> Symmetric Passive (2): This type of association is ordinarily created
>   upon arrival of a message from a peer operating in the symmetric active
>   mode and persists only as long as the peer is reachable and operating at
>   a stratum level less than or equal to the host; otherwise, the
>   association is dissolved. However, the association will always persist
>   until at least one message has been sent in reply. By operating in this
>   mode the host announces its willingness to synchronize and be
>   synchronized by the peer.
>
> Client (3): A host operating in this mode sends periodic messages
>   regardless of the reachability state or stratum of its peer. By
>   operating in this mode the host, usually a LAN workstation, announces
>   its willingness to be synchronized by, but not to synchronize the peer.
>
> Server (4): This type of association is ordinarily created upon arrival
>   of a client request message and exists only in order to reply to that
>   request, after which the association is dissolved. By operating in this
>   mode the host, usually a LAN time server, announces its willingness to
>   synchronize, but not to be synchronized by the peer.
>
> Broadcast (5): A host operating in this mode sends periodic messages
>   regardless of the reachability state or stratum of the peers. By
>   operating in this mode the host, usually a LAN time server operating on
>   a high-speed broadcast medium, announces its willingness to synchronize
>   all of the peers, but not to be synchronized by any of them.

It seems to me, though, that any host except a leaf node would probably be in several modes. For example, I might have a local area network with three NTP servers, each in Symmetric Active (1) mode with respect to one another. They would also each be clients (3) of one of the many [public stratum two time servers](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/StratumTwoTimeServers). Lastly, they would all server as servers (4) to the many local clients.

Is the point that they're only in a given mode for a moment during the synchronization? If so, how does a host know to switch? I'm only looking for enough depth here to discuss the issue in an educated manner, not to write a custom time server.

Comment: They are association modes, not node modes.

Answer (score 2):

Operating mode does not describe how the daemon functions in general, rather it is a description of an association (normally an association between two computers).  Check the aragraph right before the modes you listed:

> Except in broadcast mode, an NTP association is formed when two peers
>   exchange messages and one or both of them create and maintain an
>   instantiation of the protocol machine, called an association. The
>   association can operate in one of five modes

For information about association modes in ntpv4 see:

http://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/assoc.html